# Selenium + js : match a date 'dd Mmmm yyyy' in a string

Tags: javascript, date, match, selenium-ide

I work on Selenium IDE. I don't know JS at all (I'm a tester, not a developer).

I'm storing this string: `"le 31 Mars 2015 à 11h02m`

```
storeText
//table[3]/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]</td>   (cell where is the date)
LongDateHour
```

Then I do this: *(with help of other post)*

```
storeEval
storedVars['LongDateHour'].match(/(\d{2}) (\D*) (\d{4})/);
DueDate
```

But it returns: `DueDate = "31 Mars 2015,31,Mars,2015"`

I want only `DueDate = "31 Mars 2015"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the parantheses:

```
storedVars['x'].match(/\\d{2} \\D* \\d{4}/);
```

Because those are indicating regex groups, which are being returned with your results. Or you could just return first element of results:

```
storedVars['x'].match(/(\\d{2}) (\\D*) (\\d{4})/)[0];
```